# Is there an alternative formula or add-in that can unpivot a table like Excel Power Query?

Tags: excel

I need to unpivot a table in Excel, by shifting (not transposing) some columns of data into a single column of data over multiple rows.

From what I have read, the Power Query add-in is exactly what I would need. However, my company still runs Excel 2010 and does not have the "Software Assurance" package, so I cannot install the Power Query add-in. Is there a formula or other method to unpivot a table without Power Query?

My data looks as follows, with the numbers under each day showing the day's consumption:

- SKU    Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday
- ABC      5         7         2           3
- DEF      1         5         2           7

I want it to look like this:

- SKU    Day    Consumption
- ABC    Monday      5
- ABC    Tuesday     7
- ABC    Wednesday   2
- ABC    Thursday    3
- DEF    Monday      1
- DEF    Tuesday     5
- DEF    Wednesday   2
- DEF    Thursday    7

I thought that transposing would work, but it swaps the rows and columns instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not what you're asking, however:
Transposing ***does*** work in your case, all you need to do after is to fill down an extra column which has all ABC/DEF/etc. values according to your transposed table's header positions.
In other words - it is just a matter of copying the header from a column to the leftmost column of your data, and copying its values down.

Assuming your data is not astronomically large - it is doable in a few minutes.
However I see that I get the same result you wish to get, so I assume this is an option:

[image]

***Alternatively***, I found this online:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1181023-formula-to-unpivot-data.html

> Re: Formula to unpivot data You need a helper in c2, copied down:
>
> =LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))+1
>
> Then in G2, this array formula:
> =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(0,--(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$A$2:$A$5)=$C$2:$C$5),0)),"")
>
> Then in H2, this ordinary formula:
> =IF(G2="","",--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&VLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE),",",REPT("
> ",125)),125*COUNTIF($G$2:G2,G2),125)))
>
> Array Formulae are a little different from ordinary formulae in that
> they MUST be confirmed by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to activate the
> array, not just ENTER.
>
> You will know the array is active when you see curly brackets { } - or
> "curly braces" for those of you in the USA, or "flower brackets" for
> those of you in India - appear around the outside of your formula. If
> you do not use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER you will (almost always) get an error
> message or an incorrect answer. Press F2 on that cell and try again.
>
> Don't type the curly brackets yourself - it won't work...